# Homeomorphism between $D^{m+n}$ and $D^m\times D^n$

Tags: general-topology

Let $D^k$ be the $k$-dimensional disk. It's easy to show that $D^{m+n}$ and  $D^m\times D^n$ are homeomorphic, but I want to write down such homeomorphism. My book suggests to use the "radial projection", but I don't know what it means in this context. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can think of $D^{m+n}$ as a ball, and $D^m \times D^n$ as a ball with some square edges (more or less). Think about $m=n=1$ and think about how a 2-ball can be expanded radially to become a square. Or perhaps think about $m=1, n=2$, and how a 3-ball can be expanded into a cylinder. Low dimensions are very visual, but the formula can be generalised without too much stress!